# Understanding overlapping mongodb projections

Tags: mongodb, projection, aggregation-framework

I'm struggling to understand how overlapping projections work in mongodb.

Here's a quick example to illustrating my conundrum (results from the [in-browser mongodb console](http://try.mongodb.org/)).

First, I created and inserted a simple document:

```js
var doc = {
  id:"universe", 
  systems: {
    1: {
      name:"milky_way",
      coords:{x:1, y:1}
    }
  }
}

db.test.insert(doc);
// doc succesfully inserted
```

Next, I try a somewhat odd projection:

```js
db.test.find({}, {"systems.1.coords":1, "systems.1":1});

//result
"_id" : ObjectId("537fd3541cdcaf1ba735becb"),
    "systems" : {
        "1" : {
            "coords" : {
                "y" : 1,
                "x" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to see the entirety of "system 1," including the name field. But it appears the deeper path to "systems.1.coords" overwrote the shallower path to just "system.1"?

I decide to test this "deeper path overrides shallower path" theory:

```js
db.test.find({}, {"systems.1.coords.x":1, "systems.1.coords":1});

//result
"_id" : ObjectId("537fd3541cdcaf1ba735becb"),
    "systems" : {
        "1" : {
            "coords" : {
                "y" : 1, // how'd this get here, but for the shallower projection?
                "x" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, my deeper projection *didn't* override the shallower one.

What gives? How is mongodb dealing with overlapping projections? I can't find the logic to it.

**EDIT:**

My confusion was stemming from what counted as a "top level" path.

This worked like I expected: `.findOne({}, {"systems.1":1, "systems":1})` (i.e., a full set of systems is returned, notwithstanding that I started with what appeared to be a "narrower" projection).

However, this did not work like I expected: `.findOne({}, {"systems.1.name":1, "systems.1":1})` (i.e., only the name field of system.1 is returned).

**In short, going more than "one dot" deep leads to the overwriting discussed in the accepted answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this sort of projection using .`find()` as the general projections allowed are basic field selection. What you are talking about is document re-shaping and for that you can use the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) operator with the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method.

So by your initial example:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "coords": "$systems.1.coords",
        "systems": 1
    }}
])
```

That will give you output like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537fe2127cb762d14e2a1007"),
    "systems" : {
            "1" : {
                    "name" : "milky_way",
                    "coords" : {
                            "x" : 1,
                            "y" : 1
                    }
            }
    },
    "coords" : {
            "x" : 1,
            "y" : 1
    }
}
```

Note the different field naming there as well, as if for no other reason, the version coming from `.find()` would result in overlapping paths ("systems" is the same) for the levels of fields you were trying to select and therefore cannot be projected as **two** fields the way you can do right here.

In much the same way, consider a statement like the following:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "systems": {
            "1": {
                "coords": "$systems.1.coords"
            }
        },
        "systems": 1
    }}
])
```

So that is not telling you it's invalid, it's just that one of the results in the projection is overwriting the other as essentially at a top level they are both callled "systems".

This is basically what you end up with when trying to do something like this with the projection method available to `.find()`. So the essential part is you need a different field name, and this is what the aggregation framework ( though not aggregating here ) allows you to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you elaborate on what violates "basic field selection"?

My use case is a game. When a player moves his ships between systems, my server will find the one document that contains that game's data (using findOne) with a projection for a subset. The only reason not to fetch the whole game document is performance.

It *feels* like what I want is basic field selection, but maybe I need to change how I'm generating my projections so as not to reach for different depths?

Comment: @akbr The problem is you are trying to select two things from essentially the same field at a top level. I've expanded the principle using $project to clearly illustrate this. It cannot be field selection when you have the same name, you need to change it. Using an aggregation pipeline with a `$match` and `$project` does exactly the same thing as `.findOne()`, but it's more flexible. It's not as if you are losing performance here, especially for one document.

Comment: Thanks for walking me through it. Once I saw the overwriting behavior kicked in "two dots deep," it all clicked.